# Unable to satisfy dependencies required by Mantle and Overcoat in Podfile

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7

I added the following to my Podfile in order to install Mantle and Overcoat

```
pod 'Mantle', '~> 2.0.5'
pod 'Overcoat', '~> 3.1.1'
```

and ran pod install. At which point it complained :

- `AFNetworking/Serialization` required by `Overcoat/Core (3.1.1)`

So I added :

```
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.6.0'
```

and ran pod install

At which point it now complains :

- `AFNetworking (~> 2.6.0)` required by `Podfile`
- `AFNetworking (= 1.3.4)` required by `Podfile.lock`

How do I resolve these seemingly unresolvable dependencies?